# Compare one row of a dataframe with the corresponding one and store the data in two separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
 Rule ID
0 51183
1 50014
2 53382
3 51893
```

With this data , I want to create another dataframe which will contain 2 columns, namely `X` and `Y`and will hold the comparison of one row with another. The result will look something like this:

```
  X      Y
51183  50014
51183  53382
51183  51893
50014  53382
50014  51893
53382  51893
```

So, what is happening here is, the first value present in the `Rule ID` column, i.e, `51183` is compared with the second value present in the second row, i.e, `50014`. So `51183` is stored in `X` column and `50014` is stored in `Y` column. Similarly, `51183` is then compared with the third row value, i.e, `53382` , and then with `51893`. So, after the first row value(`51183`) is compared with all the rows below it, the comparison will move to the next row, ie, `50014`, then this value will compare with `53382` and `51893` respectively and so on.

I tried this code, where I tried `stack()` method but it seems wrong:

```
df1 = df.stack()
df1.columns = ['X', 'Y']
```

Here `df` is the dataframe which stores the `Rule ID` data.

If you guys colud help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(df['Rule ID'], 2)), columns=['x','y'])
print (df)
       x      y
0  51183  50014
1  51183  53382
2  51183  51893
3  50014  53382
4  50014  51893
5  53382  51893
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` module, with `combinations` method:

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'Rule': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'ID': [51183, 50014, 53382, 51893]})
temp = list(itertools.combinations(list(my_df.ID), 2))
print(temp)
```

Results in:

```
[(51183, 50014),
 (51183, 53382),
 (51183, 51893),
 (50014, 53382),
 (50014, 51893),
 (53382, 51893)]
```

Comment: You're welcome, look at @jezrael solution as well, as he also creates a new dataframe with requested column names. I think we posted it simultaneously :D

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Both your answers are pretty similar ;)